# How to process streaming data conditionally in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm using Flink to develop my streaming job with Java.

In my case, there are two data source: A and B.

A keeps generating the boolean data: true or false.

I'm trying to achieve such a goal:

```
if get false from A
    get data from B and do some process
else
    do nothing
```

How could I code my streaming job?

Comment: Can You add some details ?? There are several possible options to do that but without knowing a little bit more it can be hard to propose the best solution. What's the size of B? What's the size of A? Are those both streaming sources? Do records have some notion of key ?

Comment: This example -- https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/learn-flink/etl.html#example -- from the Flink training in the documentation illustrates the basic pattern of using one stream to control another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flink works on a push model, not a pull model. So you don't "get data from B", instead your operator gets called whenever data arrives from B. Assuming you're using a broadcast stream for data source A, then you can either ignore (drop) data from B, or buffer it and process when you get a true from (but buffering in state could be challenging, depending on the data volume you might receive while waiting for the true signal from A).

Note that if B is some queue system (e.g. Kafka), then you could instead model this as a simple one-input operator from A, where your operator directly uses a Kafka consumer to pull data from the Kafka topic. Obviously more work, but a possible solution. You'd want to save the current offset in state (similar to the Flink Kafka source). And there is additional complexity with parallelism of your operator vs. number of partitions from Kafka, etc.